# How do I retrieve data from array list to ImageView?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I'm trying to display data in my imageView from my array list. However, I'm getting

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gorila.sqlite_grid_view/com.example.gorila.AvatarShop.imageView}: java.lang.NullPointerException

I'm trying to make a simple feature in which when a user bought an image from my customised list, the index in which the image is stored will be added to my array list, and then passing it into my imageView Activity Class, and then the user will be able to press a button in which the user can switch to their new bought images.

So, it will go from MainActivity -> DetailActivity -> imageView.

Main Activity:

```
int[] avatarImage = {R.mipmap.blademaster,R.mipmap.gunslinger,R.mipmap.pyro,R.mipmap.darthvader};
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.avatarlv);

MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,titles,harga,avatarImage);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("title",titles[position]);
        mIntent.putExtra("avatarImages",avatarImage[position]);
        mIntent.putExtra("harga",harga[position]);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
});
```

My Detail Activity:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mymoney > harga ) { // when my money is > price of the item
            list.add(mBundle.getInt("avatarImages"));
            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Successfully Bought the avatar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, imageView.class);
            intent.putExtra("list1", list);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Your money is not enough", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

My ImageView:

```
private int current_image_index;

ArrayList<Integer> imageBought =  (ArrayList<Integer>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list1");

    private void buttonClick()
    {
        imgView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonSw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSw);
        buttonSw.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    current_image_index++;
                    current_image_index = current_image_index % imageBought.size();
                    imgView.setImageResource(imageBought.get(current_image_index));
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView.class` is not an activity so you cannot call it with an intent like you `MainActivity.class` or `DetailActivity.class`. Also, please post your full error logs in the future so that everyone gets more context as to what your error is.

Comment: sorry but how is it not an activity? I called it with intent and it worked, the only problems i got is not being able to call the stored arrays and displaying it into the image View.  @MacLean Sochor